# expect_error function in testthat of R is not matching my error message

Tags: r, testthat

```
expect_error(func(), regexp = "2 total unused argument(s).")

Error: `func()` threw an error with unexpected message.
Expected match: "2 total unused argument(s)."
Actual message: "2 total unused argument(s)."
```

To me, the Expected match and Actual message that the error message outputs are exactly the same string. So why is it complaining?

Comment: If it's a regular expression, try escaping the brackets and period with \\ to make them literals : `expect_error(func(), regexp = "2 total unused argument\\(s\\)\\.")`

Comment: Does adding `fixed = TRUE` work?